# Delete trigger not working when executed

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Is there any posibility to delete from table2 (which has a reference from table1) after delete one row in table1? (eg: if I delete a CustomerID from Customers at the same time to delete the order he made (OrderID))

```
CREATE TRIGGER DelBilete
ON Curse 
AFTER DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM Bilete 
  WHERE IDCursa IN (SELECT IDCursa FROM Curse)
END
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. But the code you posted does not reference the virtual deleted table.

Comment: @SeanLange - I don't get it. Can you be more specific please? Maybe an example?

Comment: Look at your delete statement. That is going to delete every single row in Bilete that has a matching row in Curse. There is no condition there to only delete the Bilete row for the Curse row you just deleted. Change your subquery to select from deleted instead and it should be pretty much what you want.

Comment: Have you been able to solve your problem?

Comment: @rrrrdc  If my answer helped you, please consider marking it as your accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this:  either with a cascading delete (which you set up with your foreign key constraint):

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orders]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT    
[FK_Orders_Customer] FOREIGN KEY([customerId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer] ([customerId])
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

... or with a trigger, as you have tried.  (You might try something like this, actually.  Disclaimer:  this was from memory and not tested.)

```
CREATE TRIGGER DelBilete
ON Curse 
AFTER DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM Bilete WHERE IDCursa IN(SELECT IDCursa FROM deleted)
END
GO
```

If you just delete where the foreign key is present in the primary key table, you'll delete all your orders (or whatever `Bilete` contains)!

ETA:  On getting a foreign key constraint error:

> The delete statement conflicted with the reference constraint
>   "FK_Bilete_Curse".

If you have a foreign key constraint, and you want to delete from the primary table (`Curse`) and have the related records deleted from the related table (`Bilete`), an `AFTER` trigger won't solve the problem, precisely because it is an AFTER trigger.  It takes place after the records have been deleted.  If they can't be deleted, the trigger doesn't fire.  And if those records are referenced by other records, they can't be deleted.

So you then have two options:

1. The cascading delete, above;
2. An `INSTEAD OF trigger`.  (See [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521(v=sql.105).aspx) for more details.)

An INSTEAD OF trigger in your case would look like this (again, from memory and documentation, not tested):

```
CREATE TRIGGER DelBilete
ON Curse 
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM Bilete WHERE IDCursa IN(SELECT IDCursa FROM deleted)
   DELETE FROM Curse WHERE IDCursa IN (SELECT IDCursa from deleted)
END
GO
```

With an `INSTEAD OF` trigger, when you execute code to delete a record from `Curse`, the trigger runs instead.  It deletes the related records from `Bilete`, and then executes the delete from `Curse`.

`INSTEAD OF` triggers do not run recursively, so the DELETE from `Curse` in the trigger doesn't force another run of the trigger.

Comment: AnnL - it doesn't work the second method. The same error

Comment: What is the error?  I was thinking afterward that if you had a foreign key relationship actually set up, deleting from `Curse` before `Bilete` might give you a constraint error.  Also, if `Bilete` has any dependencies, you may have the same problem with *its* dependencies.

Comment: `IDCursa` is also present in table `Bilete` (`IDCursa`). `The delete statement conflicted with the reference constraint "FK_Bilete_Curse"`.

Comment: In this case, you have two options:  you can either set up cascading deletes on `FK_Bilete_Curse`, or you can try an `INSTEAD OF trigger` (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521(v=sql.105).aspx">).   In an `INSTEAD OF` trigger, you would perform the delete from `Bilete`, as you do in your original trigger, followed by the delete from `Curse`, so that the constraint doesn't fire.

Comment: @rrrrdc  I have updated my example to show more details.